# Drawing histogram and creating new column for spark dataframe using python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using the below python code to create a crosstab from spark dataframe.

```
age_matter = df[df['y']=='yes'].stat.crosstab("age", "y").orderBy("age_y", ascending=True).show(100)
```

I would like to know how to create a histogram based on this code.

On the other hand, I am creating a new column based on another column in the spark dataframe and I expect to use a code like the following but it is in vain.

```
if df['age']<=24:
  df['group']='Youths'
elif df['age']>=25 and df['age']<=59:
  df['group']='Adults'
else:
  df['group']='Elderly'
```

An error message displays as follows.

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Grateful for someone's help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're making some mistakes accessing the values in the dataframe;

- you should be doing this df[df['age'] <= 24 ] to select all values that fall within that condition
- df['group'] = 'Youths' will cause ALL values in the column to be 'Youths'

So you would be better off doing this;

```
df['group'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: 'Youths' if x <= 24 else 'Adults' if (x > 24) & (x <= 59) else 'Elderly')
```

Finally, you could just do something simple like this for the histogram;

```
df.hist(bins=10)
```

Comment: seems you are answering as pandas, I think he was asking for spark

Comment: You're right! My bad! I wonder if the title was edited?...